# Can I model a trend and seasonal component for a stationary time series?

Tags: stationarity, seasonality, state-space-models

I modelled quarterly german inflationdata in a state space model with a stochastic level and stochastic seasonal. But now I recognized that I need a stationary time series because I have to compare it with a Arima in state space form. According to the Augmented Dickey Fuller test the time series is stationary but by looking at the acf a seasonal pattern is observable. I took the difference between Q1 in one year and Q1 in the previous years. My question now: Can I still model a stochastic level and stochastic seasonal to the stationary time series? 
As far as I know differencing removes trend and seasonality, which is why you can never have a model with a trend or seasonal component for a stationary time series, can you?

Comment: Hi: the ss formulation doesn't require stationarity but, if you're going to include a trend and-or a seasonal, then you should probably include them in the arima model. Note that differenced models in the ARIMA formulation can be thought of containing "trend". See the arima(0,1,1) in state space form. The ss version of it is called a random walk + noise. Similarly the the ss version of the arima(0,2,2) is called local linear trend. Neither of these incorporate seasonality though. See Harvey's blue book "Strucural Models and the Kalman Filter"  for the connection between  arima and ss.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I understand you correctly that I also don't need a stationary time series for an Arima in state space form?

Comment: They do require stationarity but there are two "pseudo" ways around  that.  1) you can have a time trend in an ARIMA model because the time trend is seperate. 2) pseudo trend can be included by differencing. So, if you difference $x_t$ and model that, then one could argue that you have a model  for $x_t$ that deals with non-stationarity of $x_t$  by differencing. $x_t$ can then be thought of as difference stationary which can be viewed as $x_t$ having a trend.  Not sure if this is clear but my point is that there are ways to deal with the fact that ARIMA models require stationarity.